# LDAP Bind request failing

Tags: ldap

I have a Windows Server 2008 R2 Active Directory domain controller with domain `madhurmoss.com`

I have a Linux box which is trying to connect to LDAP (389) on above box, which is failing.

Upon inspection in Wireshark, I see a bind request with following query
`sAMAccountName=Administrator,DC=madhurmoss,DC=com`

and result with

`invalid Credentials 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C0903A9, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v1db0`

I want it to connect it through Administrator which lies in 
`CN=Administrator,CN=Users,DC=madhurmoss,DC=com`

The supplied credentials are correct. I believe the query `sAMAccountName=Administrator,DC=madhurmoss,DC=com` is wrong.

Can anyone guide me what could be wrong ?

Comment: What is your bind command?  Are you specifying the username and password?  Sounds like that is what you need to do.  Also, probably better to do that over LDAP/SSL port 636.

Answer (score 2):

Use `CN=Administrator,CN=Users,DC=madhurmoss,DC=com` as your binddn string. That should do it.

Comment: Its not working. I even tried (&(samAccountName=Administrator,CN=Users,DC=madhurmoss,DC=com)(objectClass=user)) . But no result. I am trying in LDAP Browser as well.

Comment: That's a filter, not a DN

Answer (score 1):

I usually use [Apache Directory Studio](http://directory.apache.org/studio/) to graphically browse to what is needed and then I right click and Copy DN from there. Makes things a ton easier. Not that LDAP formatting is tricky but it has saved me on typos, switching CN for OU, etc.

Give a go with that and see how it works. Plus, it'll let you know if it is a permissions issue you are having.

Comment: I am using LDAP Browser for the same. I tried the solution suggested by mgabriel but its not working.

Comment: What does your config on the linux box look like? What about your hierarchy in AD - is it like above or is the administrator account in some other folder than "Users"?

Answer (score 1):

The string **sAMAccountName=Administrator,DC=madhurmoss,DC=com** isn't a valid X.500 definition.  The attribute **sAMAccountName** is a valid attribute for all Security Principals, but it's not a valid X.500 node type (DC, OU or CN are).  I'd be looking at your LDAP bind definition.  What LDAP implementation are you using?

Comment: Active Directory

Comment: Sorry, I meant client-side.